# Toyama bay firefly squids

Tags: japan, self-guided

We're planing a trip to Japan next year, and wanted to include the firefly squids of Toyama bay too. My problem is that I can't find any more information about the location/timing/possibilities besides that it's at night, probably on the eastern side of the bay and there is a museum that does cruises to which tickets sell out fast.
So here are some questions to start with:
Is it enough to get to the shore after dark, or does it need to be way into the night just like as the cruise leaves (at 3 am)?
Is it possible to see the squid from the shore or you must out on sea?
Are there other possibilities to get out or just the museum's cruise and where to find them?
Anyone got some experience with this and willing to share?

Thanks!

Comment: So i'm guessing no one was at this spot or no one can help me out with info..

Answer (score 2):

The museum has an English page.  http://hotaruikamuseum.com/en/museum

On the "Business hours" page, it mentions that the firefly squid can usually be seen between March 20 and June 1.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Japanese-language sites I looked at tell me about the following conditions:

- They often appear on the shore, so you don't need to take a tour
- They are hard to see except in the middle of the night, at high tide
- If you can choose a day, choose a new moon